# What C# / Win32 Control Is the Wireless Network Dialog Using?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, windows-vista, controls

I'm working on an application, and I have a screen that in my mind, looks a lot like the Wireless Network List in Windows Vista.  For those who are unaware, its basically a listview, but in each row, instead of a line of text, there's a large 'panel' that contains all sorts of useful information.  Does anyone know if that's an actual UI control available on windows, or should I roll my own with some sort of autosizing table layout panel hosting a collection of custom controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is pretty easy to make using WPF using the stackpanel layout along with a series of user controls containing grid controls for internal layout. Or are you using windows forms?

Comment: Yea, I'm using Windows Forms.  I know I can do it with a custom control and a table, but if there's an easier way, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0):

The wireless network dialog isn't using a standard Win32 control, it's using a custom control (effectively).

If you want to emulate that behavior, you're going to have to use WPF or roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but you may want to look at the various Vista TaskDialog libraries and dialogs that have been based on that. You may be able to borrow some of the code since they share some UI functionality. I need to do the something similar with WPF.